# QGIS Relations loss of form style

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm currently creating a project for management of highway drains in QGIS which involves the recording the feature attributes and logging of multiple inspections against a feature. I have a layer for the highway_drains and a separate layer for highway_inspections, utilizing the RELATIONS function under project properties works perfectly for the Parent/Child relationship of highway drains to inspections.

I used the drag and drop designer for both layers to reference lookups and style the form. However in order to view/edit the inspections within the form for highway_drains, I have to switch the highway_drains layer from 'drag and drop' designer to auto generate. This results in the lose of the form styling for the highway_drains layer, namely the TABS and order of fields (lookups and field aliases are preserved), styling for highway_inspections is preserved.

My Question: How can I preserve the form style for highway drains?

I'm using QGIS version 2.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have to switch to auto-generate? All you need to do is open the relations section in the fields tab and drag the relation over to your form that you are building with the drag and drop designer. If you can't do this, then you may need to provide information on your relationship of other project properties

[image]s

Here is the form view with the sub form
[image]